# AngularJS - Validation for Saving and Creating/Publishing

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation

We are developing an website to allow product managers save and create products.

The save has some basic validation for any data that's been entered. 
The create/publish has all validation including required data checks.

**Is there a good way to have two different types of validation for a single form?**

Below are a couple of approaches that I've tried:

**ng-required**

```
<input type="text" name="planName" ng-model="vm.product.planName" ng-required="vm.publishAttempt" />
```

Our save marks the form as pristine.

```
    function saveSuccess()
    {
        vm.editForm.$setPristine();
        vm.publishAttempt = false;
        vm.isLoading = false;
    }
```

This makes it so the form inputs with ng-required are not triggered for validation when the publish button is clicked and a true value is set to validate them. The only solution I've seen for this is to loop over the form elements and mark them as dirty. It seems like the wrong approach though.

```
    function publish()
    {
        vm.isLoading = true;
        vm.publishAttempt = true;

        angular.forEach(vm.editForm, function (field)
        {
            if (field && field.$pristine != null)
            {
                console.log(field);
                field.$setDirty();
            }
        });

        setTimeout(function()
        {
            if (vm.editForm.$invalid)
            {
                vm.isLoading = false;
                logger.error('Required data is missing. Please check the form and try again.');
            }
            else
            {
                if ($window.confirm('Are you sure you want to publish this product? Doing so will make this product available to everyone and any changes going forward will be considered corrections to the product. '))
                {
                    productService.publishProduct($routeParams.productId)
                        .then(publishSuccess, publishFail);
                }
                else
                {
                    vm.isLoading = false;
                    vm.publishAttempt = false;
                }
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
```

**back end validation using fluentvalidation**

We also have back end validation using FluentValidation. I've tried returning those results but would then have to loop over all of them and find the value on the form and mark it as invalid.

```
    function publishSuccess(result)
    {
        if (!result.IsValid)
        {
            angular.forEach(result.errors, function(error)
            {
                // Map error back to input and set invalid.  
            });        
        }
        else
        {
            openDetail($routeParams.productId);
        }
        vm.isLoading = false;
    }
```

It's extremely tempting to default to jQuery for a solution but there has to be an AngularJS way that I am simply just missing.

I'm fairly new to Angular, am I missing anything obvious?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added vm.publishAttempt to my view model on my edit controller and set it to false.

```
function Edit(productService, logger, $routeParams, $location, $timeout, $modal, ...)
{
    var vm = this;
    vm.publishAttempt = false;
    vm.save = save;
    vm.publish = publish;
    // ...
```

In the view I put ng-required attribute on all inputs that are required by a publish.

```
ng-required="vm.publishAttempt"
```

On save I set the publishAttempt to false so that all of the publish specific errors are cleared from view. When a save is successful the form is set back to a pristine state.

```
    function save()
    {
        vm.publishAttempt = false;

        $timeout(function()
        {
            if (vm.editForm.$invalid)
            {
                vm.isLoading = false;
                logger.error('Required data is missing. Please check the form and try again.');
            }
            else
            {
                productService
                    .saveProduct(vm.product)
                    .$promise
                    .then(saveSuccess, saveFail);
            }
        }, 500);
    }

    function saveSuccess()
    {
        vm.editForm.$setPristine();
        vm.publishAttempt = false;
    }

    function saveFail(error)
    {
        // Display errors
    }
```

On publish I mark publishAttempt to true and then make all form inputs dirty to display the errors. Then we check to see if the form is invalid. If it is we let the user know via a logger message to the browser.

```
    function publish()
    {
        vm.publishAttempt = true;

        setAllInputsDirty(vm.editForm);

        $timeout(function()
        {
            if (vm.editForm.$invalid)
            {
                logger.error('Required data is missing. Please check the form and try again.');
            }
            else
            {
                if ($window.confirm('Are you sure ... ?'))
                {
                    productService.publishProduct($routeParams.productId)
                        .then(publishSuccess, publishFail);
                }
                else
                {
                    vm.publishAttempt = false;
                }
            }
        }, 500);
    }

    function publishSuccess(result)
    {
        // If there are errors display them. 
        // This shouldn't happen because the front end validation should find these first.
        // These are the server side errors from FluentValidation
        if (!result.IsValid)
        {
            $modal.open({
                templateUrl: '/app/edit/server-errors.html',
                controller: 'ServerErrors',
                controllerAs: 'vm',
                size: 'lg',
                resolve: {
                    errors: function ()
                    {
                        return result.errors;
                    }
                }
            });

            return;
        }

        openDetail($routeParams.productId);
        logger.info('Product successfully published.');
        vm.isLoading = false;
    }

    function publishFail(error)
    {
        vm.isLoading = false;
        logger.error('Publish failed', error);
    }
```

This is the method that's used to make all inputs dirty in order to get the conditional validation working for publish. It's a close copy of the URL in the comment below.

```
    // http://blog.pixelastic.com/2014/09/10/setting-all-inputs-as-$dirty-in-angularjs-1.2/
    function setAllInputsDirty(form)
    {
        _.each(form, function (value, key)
        {
            // We skip non-form and non-inputs
            if (!value || value.$dirty === undefined)
            {
                return;
            }

            // Recursively applying same method on all forms included in the form
            if (value.$addControl)
            {
                return setAllInputsDirty(value);
            }

            return value.$setDirty();
        });
    }
}
```